Mapping ICollection<string> to JSON column in EF Core 8
I'm using EF Core 8, with the Postgres adapter.
I need this entity property as JSON:
public ICollection<string> Messages { get; } = [];

I tried this configuration:
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Messages, x => x.ToJson());

That didn't work as it saved "{ Capacity: 4 }" in the database.
I tried this configuration:
builder.Property(x => x.Messages).HasColumnType("jsonb");

That throws a NotSupportedException.
I tried various other combinations and workarounds.
For years now, although JSON mapping has been improved, there are always bugs or shortcomings.
I know that .NET 9 was released yesterday, possibly with some improvements for collections of primitives and strings, but we can't upgrade now.
What works in .NET 8?
(Docs are here and here.)

Do you have a good reason for having a denormalized DB like this? If not, you should avoid storing JSON blobs and instead use your RDBMS as an RDBMS and not like it's MongoDB...

@Dai Yes we have various items which we store as JSON. Both EF and the db provider support that use case, but are riddled with bugs.

...that doesn't really answer my question, though.

We have various places where we store frontend-related data as JSON. And simple data like string[] . Some stuff is never directly processed and doesn't require normalisation or useless extra tables. Json in a rdbms has it's place.

I found the answer in the docs for value converters. It serialises to json despite not using HasColumnType("jsonb") or ToJson().
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Customer>()
  .Property(x => x.Messages)
  //.HasColumnType("jsonb")      // unnecessary
  .HasConversion(
    c => JsonSerializer.Serialize(c, JsonSerializerOptions.Default),
    s => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ICollection<string>>(s, JsonSerializerOptions.Default)!,
    new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
      (c1, c2) => c1!.SequenceEqual(c2!),
      c => c.Aggregate(0, (acc, val) => HashCode.Combine(acc, val.GetHashCode(StringComparison.Ordinal))),
      c => new Collection<string>(c.ToList()))
  );

Example:
customer.Messages.Add("foo");
customer.Messages.Add("bar");
customer.Messages.Add("baz");

The db record will have:
["foo","bar","baz"]

